# Javascript: abort the function

Tags: javascript

There is function, which when called, takes few minutes to complete.
Functions gets list of available courses then calls another service to get course's details.

When functions gets called, I need to stop previous instances of it ( if any ). How can I achieve that?

I've written code piece bellow. is it a good idea? if i call `cancel.abort` will it only stop the main function or also all it's nested service calls?

```js
const customXmlHttpRequest = (url, opts={}, cancel={}, timeoutMS = 30000) => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(opts.method || 'get', url);
  xhr.timeout = timeoutMS; // time in milliseconds
  for (var k in opts.headers || {}){
    xhr.setRequestHeader(k, opts.headers[k]);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    xhr.onload = e => resolve(e.target);
    cancel.abort = () => {
      xhr.abort();
      reject(new Error("Cancelled"))
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.ontimeout = () => {
      reject(new Error("Timeout"))
    }
    xhr.send(opts.body);
  });
}

const getCourses = (cancel) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    cancel.abort = ()=>{
      reject(new Error('Cancelled'))
    }
    customXmlHttpRequest('/courselist', {}, cancel)
      .then((res)=>{
        let response = res._reponse.json();
        response.forEach((id)=>{
          customXmlHttpRequest('/coursedetails'+id, {}, cancel)
      .then((res)=>{
        let response = res._reponse.json();
        //// do the rest
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        reject(e);
       })
       .done();
        })
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        reject(e);
       })
       .done();
  })
}


///////////

let cancel = {};
getCourses(cancel);
cancel.abort()
```

After calling `getCourses(cancel)` , if I call `cancel.abort()`, would it abort all running functions and service calls?

Comment: "After calling getCourses(cancel) , if I call cancel.abort(), would it abort all running functions and service calls?" - Have you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to test it. so before spending more time on it, I asked it here to see if there is any better solution/implementation.